# Detecting what row a google spreadsheet is in

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is there a way to make a formula that would detect what row it's in and I can copy and paste it into all instead of typing out a different formula for each one, since I have a very big spreadsheet.

I.E Divide column A, Current Row by two.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood this correctly, you can have arrayformula in cell F2 that references E2:E. No need to figure out the rows... try:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(E2:E), E2:E/2,))
```

Note: according to your locale you may have to replace the comma's with semi colons.